# SSL chain of trust with browser-sync?

Tags: browser-sync

I'm trying to set up a gulp HTTPS server. My server's certificate is signed by my company's CA. In order for it to be validated by a browser, the CA's certificate itself also needs to be specified, so that the client browser can validate the chain of trust.

Node's HTTPS object has an option "ca" for listing trusted certificates to establish the chain of trust. Is there a way to specify ca certs in browser-sync? Optimally, I'd be looking for something like the snippet below, but I'd take a workaround, if there are any.

```
browserSync.instance = browserSync.init({
  server: {
    baseDir: "app",
    index: "index.htm"
  },
  https: {
    cert: './certs/serverCert.pem,
    key: './certs/serverKey.pem',
    ca: ['./certs/mycompany-ca.cer', './certs/mycompany-root-ca.cer']
  }
});
```

Comment: Same problem here: for development, I'm using an internal CA (self-signed) and a server certificate issued by that CA. Browsersync rejects connections with «Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain». Haven't found a way to configure a truststore or CA certs yet...